# How to have a scope to elements in array - Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I have a question about jquery . I created an array containing the names of the current class elements ' li ' . I would like to click on another element to remove class ' active' from the previous item and assign it the class contained in the array. Here is my piece of code responsible for this action :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = [];

$('li').each(function (index){
    console.log(index + ':' + $(this).attr('class'));
    classes = [$(this).attr('class')];
    classes.toString();
    console.log(classes);
});

$('FirstElement').click(function(){
    if($('#FirstElement').hasClass('done')){
    console.log('It has done class');
}else{
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('active');
    $('#SecondElement').removeClass('active').addClass(classes[1]);
    $('#ThirdElement').removeClass('active').addClass(classes[2]);
    $('#FourthElement').removeClass('active').addClass(classes[3]);
}
});
```

The element 'classes[0]' etc. is undefined. How I can use the name of the class by the 'classes[0]' etc.? Thanks for your reply.

EDIT: Of course. Thanks for fast reply.

---

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<ul id="ListOfCircles" class="qz-steps" role="">
<span id="FirstElement_block">
<li id="FirstElement" class="next" role="">
<i id="FirstItemIcon" class="icon-done fa fa-check" onclick="changeToBasicInfo();"></i>
<div id="FirstItemNumber" class="qz-step-text" onclick="" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-top: 0px;display:none">
<label class=" ThemeGrid_Width2" style="" for="">1</label>
</div>
<div id="FirstItemDescription" class="qz-step-desc" style="margin-top: 0px"></div>
</li>
</span>
<span id="SecondElement_block">
<li id="SecondElement" class="" role="">
<i id="SecondItemIcon" class="icon-done fa fa-check">  
</i>
<div id="SecondItemNumber" class="qz-step-text" onclick="" style="margin-top: 0px">
<label class=" ThemeGrid_Width2" style="" for="" onclick="changeToExperience();">2</label>
</div>
<div id="SecondItemDescription" class="qz-step-desc" style="margin-top: 0px">
</div>
</li>
</span>
<span id="ThirdElement_block">
<li id="ThirdElement" class="active" role="">
<i id="ThirdItemIcon" class="icon-done fa fa-check">
</i>
<div id="ThirdItemNumber" class="qz-step-text" onclick="" style="margin-top: 0px">
<label class=" ThemeGrid_Width2" style="" for="" onclick="changeToPreferences();">3</label>
</div>
<div id="ThirdItemDescription" class="qz-step-desc" style="margin-top: 0px">
</div>
</li>
</span>
<span id="FourthElement_block"><li id="FourthElement" class="next" role="">
<i id="FourthItemIcon" class="icon-done fa fa-check"></i>
<div id="FourthItemNumber" class="qz-step-text" onclick="" style="margin-top: 0px">
<label class=" ThemeGrid_Width2" style="" for="" onclick="changeToPrice();">4</label>
</div>
<div id="FourthItemDescription" class="qz-step-desc" style="margin-top: 0px">
</div>
</li>
</span>
</ul>
```

The css is here:

```css
qz-step-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li {
  width: calc(16.66666667%);
  color: #CDD0DC;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li .icon-done {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: none;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0 auto 0;
  z-index: -2;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.active {
  color: #fee103;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 1;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.active:before {
  border: 2px solid #fee103;
  z-index: 1;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.next {
  color: #fee103;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 0;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.next:before {
  border: 2px solid #E1E1E1;
  z-index: 0;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.done {
  color: #fee103;
  cursor: default;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.done .icon-done {
  display: inherit;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.done .qz-step-text {
  display: none;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.done:before {
  background: #fee103;
  border: 2px solid #fee103;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.done:after {
  background: #fee103;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.disabled {
  cursor: default;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li.disabled:before {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(10) {
  z-index: 10;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(9) {
  z-index: 9;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(8) {
  z-index: 8;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(7) {
  z-index: 7;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(6) {
  z-index: 6;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 5;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 4;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 3;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}
qz-step-container qz-steps li:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you making it so complex? Can you put html so that i can give u a simpler solution.

Comment: Can you provide html?

Comment: I guess you are not pushing elements correctly. Try classes.push($(this).attr('class'))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var lis = $("#ListOfCircles li");
lis.on("click",function(){
  lis.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Ok, Thats work like before. Maybe i have problem with css (not my css). Could u take a look on this? I add the actitve class to the 'next' class but its not visible in browser. I will add my css to this thread.